# Export Data to file in GNU Radio Companion

Tags: file, export, gnuradio

I have run into a slight problem with GNU Radio. I inserted a “File Sink” block into GNU Radio companion. I was receiving data last week, but coming back to the classroom today, I am not able to execute the file anymore. Do you have any idea what is wrong?

Basically, what I am trying to do, is export data created from GRC file using a file sink block to export the data to a file. That file, using python to parse through the data, will then be uploaded to a database. My problem is now that I cannot execute the file to export the data.

Below is some data from the Python script associated with the File Sink

```
audiodata =  gr.file_sink(gr.sizeof_float, "audio.dat")
self.connect(src0, audio)


audiodata = gr.file_sink(gr.sink(gr.sizeof_complex, "audio.dat")
```

Below is a link of my GRC File.

http://i58.tinypic.com/10wv78z.png

If anyone has a better way to export the data from GRC, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The second line of python looks broken. Where did you get it from? I haven't seen a bug in GRC's python code generation yet, so this is surprising.

Regarding the red arrow: This most probably indicates that something is wrong with the data type of the file sink. You should set the type to float, set it back to complex, and see if that solved the problem. If it did not, then your GRC file is broken, and you'll either need to manually look at the XML or re-build it from scratch, sorry :(

I have not seen XML corruption in GRC, either, so please make sure your data storage is not corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

I think the second line should be 
    `self.connect(src0, audiodata)`

The lines looks similar to [Capturing Signals in GNU Radio.pdf](https://www.csun.edu/~skatz/katzpage/sdr_project/sdr/capture_sigs.pdf)  available in internet